# Is it possible to set Wordwrap in WebStorm? I need to set by default all the files should be in wordwraping

Tags: word-wrap, webstorm

is there any way to set word-wrap for all new/existing files should be in word-wrapping.

i need to set by default all the file in word-wrapping like notepadd++.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Use soft wraps in editor** -- this setting affects all files.

You can disable or enable this option on per file basis (until it's closed) via **View | Active Editor | Use Soft Wraps**

More recent version (compared to the versions available when this question was answered) also have these options available in the Editor's gutter menu (right click in the area where the line numbers/breakpoints/etc are).

---

**P.S.**

Settings screen has very nice feature -- **quick search box (top left corner)** -- it does wonders. It allows you to quickly narrow the search scope of the specific setting by it's name (keyword).

You can also use "Search anywhere" (<kbd>Shift</kbd> two times) as well as "Find Action" (`Help | Find Action...` <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>) to search for individual settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell me for windows.. i need to set once for all the time use

Comment: 1) Tell you what "for windows"? 2) *"i need to set once for all the time use"* Did I say anywhere that it will work differently?

Comment: we can set a wordwrap using softwrapers but need to set each and every time a file is opened. but i need a permanent set for wordwrap.. got my question

Comment: *"but i need a permanent set for wordwrap.. got my question"* -- and **I gave you the answer** -- **have you tried it**? .. or is it just typical trend these days to answer: "I have not tried yet .. but my astrologist (who knows nothing about this) thinks that it may not be the right thing)" ?

Comment: In WS 10 it even allows you to change the setting (or at least toggle on/off) from right there within the quick search pane. Very slick.

Answer (score 14):

Webstorm 9.0.3 Evaluation version on Windows 7:

I know I'm a bit late coming here, but if like me, you find that there's no "**Use soft wraps in editor**" option when you look in `Settings>Editor>`, i just discovered you can apply 'soft wrap' to *individual* files:

- Open the file,
- Left click the left margin (where the line numbers are),
- You'll see "Use Soft Wraps" as an option you can turn on.

It's not quite what I wanted (change settings to apply to all files), but it's something.

Comment: It is possible to turn on "Use Soft Wraps" for all files.  Win 7 uses the same menu location as the Mac, [reference this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21405348/404699).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible. I have webstorm 2016. Follow these step.

**Step 1:**

This step may vary depending on OS used. Just search for preferences. I have screenshot for Mac.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Click on Editor twice. Note that arrow will change to downward position as shown.

[image]

**Step 3 :**

Click on general and see the option `Use soft wraps in editor`.

[image]

**Step 4:**

Select it and click ok

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | **General** | Use soft wraps in editor

Although its an old thread but updating as someone may find it usefull. In version 9.0.1, you have to select **General** inside **Editor** and then **Use soft wraps in editor**

Comment: Further update (Jan 2021): I'm now not seeing an option to just enable it for everything. You now have to choose "Soft-wrap these files" and give patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Settings(ctrl+alt+s)--->Editor--->general--->use soft wrap in editor